# Is TableAdapter/DataSet safe from SQL injection?

Tags: asp.net, sql, code-injection

In my ASP.NET(3.5) project, I am using inbuilt TableAdapters/Dataset for all Data Access. Does it provide the same security as SQLDataSource does from SQL injection? I am using parameters as follows.

```
Dim myDAL As New ABCTableAdapters.XYZTableAdapter
Label1.Text = myDAL.getDatafromDB(myParameter)
```

**Update 1:**

```
     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Dim myParameter As String = getSafeURL(Request.QueryString("MS_Code")) 'getsafeurl encodes querystring using HttpUtility.UrlEncode
            Dim myDAL As New ABCTableAdapters.XYZTableAdapter
            Label1.Text = myDAL.getDatafromDB(myParameter)
     End Sub
```

getDatafromDB corresponds to following query present in app_code/DAL.xsd

SELECT something FROM sometable where fieldname = @parameter

**Update 2:**
If I 'View Code' of XSD I am able to see following

```
<SelectCommand>
              <DbCommand CommandType="Text" ModifiedByUser="true">
                <CommandText>SELECT pageContent FROM [content] where name = @name</CommandText>
                <Parameters>
                  <Parameter AllowDbNull="true" AutogeneratedName="name" ColumnName="name" DataSourceName="iseac.dbo.[content]" DataTypeServer="nchar(100)" DbType="String" Direction="Input" ParameterName="@name" Precision="0" ProviderType="NChar" Scale="0" Size="100" SourceColumn="name" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Current" />
                </Parameters>
              </DbCommand>
            </SelectCommand>
```

Comment: Could you show how the `getDatafromDB` method look like?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - please refer the update

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

You could get SQL injection if you badly use tableAdapters.

The main thing is to use SqlParameters for all data that is gathered from users.

Can you show some of your data access code ?

Look up here [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
   SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
   "SELECT au_lname, au_fname FROM Authors WHERE au_id = @au_id", 
     connection);                
   myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@au_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11);
   myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters["@au_id"].Value = SSN.Text;
   myDataAdapter.Fill(userDataset);
}
```

The important part here is that user entered data (what comes in from web request) is passed to DB inside database parameters like @au_id. In that case you are protected from SQL injection.

BAD WAY would be this (DON'T USE THIS):

```
myCommandText = string.Format(
   "SELECT au_lname, au_fname 
    FROM Authors WHERE au_id = {0}", SSN.Text)
```

This way user can manipulate what is send to DB and if your connection to DB has enough privileges it can drop tables or database. Or it can silently modify your data and that is even worse.

So, always use database parameters.

Additionally if you do you gain in performance, because DB will cache execution plan and if you later execute same SQL with only different values for parameters, DB already have execution plan and it doesn't need to parse sql again.

Comment: Do you have somewhere nearby something like 
new SqlParameter("@parameter", SlqType.Varchar) ?

Comment: please refer Update 2. Isn't it same using typed parameters. My only concern is does it qualify same security as ADO.NET parametrized queries advisable to prevent SQLi

Comment: Also refer this article by Scott Gu in which he mentions ... TableAdapter/DataSet designer built-into VS 2005 uses this mechanism automatically     http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/30/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Guard-Against-SQL-Injection-Attacks.aspx

Comment: You are looking at Dataset.xsd document. You should better look at Dataset.Designer.vb code (in solution explorer click on "Show all files" and look under DataSet's node). This is what gets compiled and executed.

Comment: Jup. Scott Gu also tells that if you are using datasets/tableadapters you are safe. But note that datasets/table adapters are not the preferred way to implement your data access these days. Use an ORM instead (LINQ2SQL, NHibernate, Entity Framework, ...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4159/discussion-between-pradeep-kalugade-and-petar-repac)